# A newline before the class closing paren

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is it possible to configure checkstyle to check whether a class is always finished with `\n}\n` sequence - I mean a `\n` before closing paren `}` in particular? E.g.:

```
class Cls {

   void m() {
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check that there are two newlines before a brace and EOF.

```
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="format" value="\n\n}\n\Z"/>
    <property name="message" value="No extra line before last right curly"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any specific check but I think you could use the [Regexp](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html) check. According to its spec since it works in multiline mode, we have to use `\Z` to match the end of the file :

```
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="format" value="\n\n}\n\Z"/>
</module>
```

Edit : that's two `\n` before the brace, as mentioned by @flkes.